# C - popen not showing right output

Tags: c, file, popen

anyone know how I can fix this?

```
char bash_cmd[256] = "curl";
char buffer[1000];
FILE *pipe;
int len; 

pipe = popen(bash_cmd, "r");


if (NULL == pipe) {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(1);
} 
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pipe);
printf("OUTPUT: %s", buffer);
pclose(pipe);
```

The above code snippit is returning the following:

```
OUTPUT: (�3B
```

instead of what it should be returning which is:

```
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Something is wrong, I can't figure out what. When I replace "curl" with, say, "ls -la" it works fine, but for whatever reason only when I use curl, it doesn't properly save the output into buffer. What could I do to fix this?? thanks in advance

Also, replacing "curl" with the full path to curl, (/usr/bin/curl) doesn't work either. ;(

Comment: To start with, you have failed to check the return value of your functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code, I find that the output is indeed approximately what you describe, but that the output you expect is also printed immediately previous.  It seems highly likely, therefore, that `curl` is printing the usage message to its `stderr` rather than to its `stdout`, as indeed it should do.

You do not check the return value of `fgets()`; I suspect you would find that it is `NULL`, indicating that the end of the stream occurred before any data was read.  In that case, I do not think `fgets()` modifies the provided buffer.

If you want to capture `curl`'s `stderr` in addition to its `stdout`, then you can apply I/O redirection to the problem:

```
char bash_cmd[256] = "curl 2>&1";
```

That would not work (directly) with the `execve()`-family functions, but `popen()` runs the given command via a shell, which should handle the redirection operator just fine.

For general purposes, however, combining `curl`'s output and error streams may not be what you want.  If both real output and real diagnostics were emitted then they would be intermingled.

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of my answer :(

Answer (score 0):

The output you expect from `curl` is going to `stderr` not `stdout`.  In fact nothing is written to `stdout`.  The output you are printing is the uninitialized contents of the buffer.

Your code should check the return value of [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), which will be null if no characters were read (or if an error occurred).